# closure-common: sbcl borks because standard readtable modified

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I updated quicklisp to the latest February version and went to re-run a few of my unit tests for the `xlmanip` workbook/worksheet reader I'm developing. SBCL borks on the unit test because it recompiles the `closure-common` package and `closure-common` modifies the standard readtable (in a nice way, actually.)

My one option is to fork the `closure-common` code base, hope that the maintainer actually responds to the patch, and pray that the patch is accepted, follow `clozure-common` dependencies in quicklisp where `SET-DISPATCH-MACRO-CHARACTER` is also called for the same reason.

Does anyone know of a workaround for this problem? `closure-common` isn't the only package that has this issue, I'm fairly certain.

EDIT: If I have to clone and hack `clozure-common`, what is the recommended/preferred way for localizing readtable modifications or switching to a custom readtable?

EDIT #2: Here's the output transcript using a freshly installed quicklisp (specifically, look at the last line of `closure-common-20101107-git/syntax.lisp` where the call to `SET-DISPATCH-MACRO-CHARACTER` occurs):

```
To load "xlmanip/tests":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    xlmanip/tests
; Loading "xlmanip/tests"
.
;;; Checking for wide character support... WARNING: Lisp implementation doesn't use UTF-16, but accepts surrogate code points.
 yes, using code points.
..
;;; Checking for wide character support... WARNING: Lisp implementation doesn't use UTF-16, but accepts surrogate code points.
 yes, using code points.
;;; Building Closure with CHARACTER RUNES
........While evaluating the form starting at line 4, column 0
  of #P"/tmp/xlmanip17497a.lisp":
Fatal condition:
SET-DISPATCH-MACRO-CHARACTER would modify the standard readtable.
See also:
  The ANSI Standard, Section 2.1.1.2
  The ANSI Standard, Glossary entry for "standard readtable"
Backtrace for: #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1002A7D263}>
0: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SB-DEBUG::FUNCALL-WITH-DEBUG-IO-SYNTAX))
1: (SB-IMPL::CALL-WITH-SANE-IO-SYNTAX #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SB-DEBUG::FUNCALL-WITH-DEBUG-IO-SYNTAX) {1006B1F8BB}>)
2: (SB-IMPL::%WITH-STANDARD-IO-SYNTAX #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SB-DEBUG::FUNCALL-WITH-DEBUG-IO-SYNTAX) {1006B1F88B}>)
3: (SB-DEBUG:PRINT-BACKTRACE :STREAM #<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM for "standard error" {1003135713}> :START 0 :FROM :DEBUGGER-FRAME :COUNT 4611686018427387903 :PRINT-THREAD T :PRINT-FRAME-SOURCE NIL :METHOD-FRAME-STYLE NIL :EMERGENCY-BEST-EFFORT NIL)
4: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN UIOP/IMAGE:PRINT-BACKTRACE))
5: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN UIOP/STREAM:CALL-WITH-SAFE-IO-SYNTAX))
6: (SB-IMPL::%WITH-STANDARD-IO-SYNTAX #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN UIOP/STREAM:CALL-WITH-SAFE-IO-SYNTAX) {1006B1F86B}>)
7: (UIOP/IMAGE:PRINT-CONDITION-BACKTRACE #<SB-INT:STANDARD-READTABLE-MODIFIED-ERROR {1006B1D643}> :STREAM #<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM for "standard error" {1003135713}> :COUNT NIL)
8: (UIOP/IMAGE:HANDLE-FATAL-CONDITION #<SB-INT:STANDARD-READTABLE-MODIFIED-ERROR {1006B1D643}>)
9: (SIGNAL #<SB-INT:STANDARD-READTABLE-MODIFIED-ERROR {1006B1D643}>)
10: (CERROR "Frob it anyway!" SB-INT:STANDARD-READTABLE-MODIFIED-ERROR :OPERATION SET-DISPATCH-MACRO-CHARACTER)
11: (SET-DISPATCH-MACRO-CHARACTER #\# #\/ RUNES::RUNE-READER #<READTABLE {100041EA83}>)
12: (SB-FASL::LOAD-FASL-GROUP #S(SB-FASL::FASL-INPUT :STREAM #<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM for "file <homedir>/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-1.3.1.243-55a6786-macosx-x64/<homedir>/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/closure-common-20101107-git/syntax.fasl" {1006B0F693}> :TABLE #(282 SET *PACKAGE* "RUNES" #<PACKAGE "SB-IMPL"> SB-IMPL::%DEFUN #<PACKAGE "RUNES"> RUNES::RT-WHITE-SPACE-P STRING MAKE-STRING-INPUT-STREAM :EOF PEEK-CHAR ...) :STACK #(0 SET-DISPATCH-MACRO-CHARACTER #\# #\/ RUNES::RUNE-READER 0 50 "<homedir>/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/closure-common-20101107-git/syntax.lisp" #<SB-KERNEL:LAYOUT for SB-C:DEFINITION-SOURCE-LOCATION {10000415B3}> NIL NIL NIL ...) :DEPRECATED-STUFF NIL :SKIP-UNTIL NIL) NIL)
<...truncated... error occurs in syntax.lisp>
```

The script that generates this output:

```
#!/bin/sh

tmpf=/tmp/xlmanip$$a.lisp
cat >${tmpf} <<__EOF__
(proclaim '(optimize speed space))
;;; SBCL:Muffle compiler-notes
#+sbcl (declaim (sb-ext:muffle-conditions sb-ext:compiler-note))
(ql:quickload :xlmanip/tests)
(time (asdf:oos 'asdf:test-op :xlmanip))
(quit)
__EOF__

trap "rm -f ${tmpf}" 0 1 2 3 15

if test "x${CL_LISPS}" = x; then
  CL_LISPS="sbcl ccl clisp ecl"
fi

for l in $CL_LISPS; do
  echo "\n======== $l ========\n"
  cl-launch --lisp $l --execute --quicklisp --init '(load "'"${tmpf}"'")'
done
```

Comment: I'm using `cl-launch` to run the 5AM unit tests, so presumably, I could copy the readtable at the beginning of the test script. However, that has nasty consequences for future users who use `xlmanip` because they'd have to do the same thing when loading `xlmanip`.

Comment: I develop using Clozure CL, which, rightly or wrongly, doesn't mind modifications to the standard readtable.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the problem, but regarding your edit, see [named-readtables](https://common-lisp.net/project/named-readtables/).

Comment: I looked at `named-readtables`, not sure if the maintainer would be receptive to adding that dependency.

Comment: @jkiiski: Heretic! Unbeliever! (Just kidding...) Updated the question with the output transcript. Actual error occurs at the last line in closure-common's syntax.lisp source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diagnosing the problem: Somewhere in the code stream that loads `closure-common`, there seems to be a call similar to:

```
(with-standard-io-syntax
  (load "closure-common"))
```

That's the only way that I've found to trip the standard `*readtable*` modification. In all other cases, e.g., from the `sbcl` prompt, `set-dispatch-macro-character` doesn't modify the standard `*readtable*`. I haven't traced the problem into ASDF, UIOP or Quicklisp itself, although those are likely candidates as well.

I've bitten the bullet, cloned the closure-common repo and decided to go with `named-readtables`. Very likely that if I publish these changes to `quicklisp`, implicitly taking maintainership, there will be ripple changes into other dependent packages that use `#"` and `#/` reader macros provided by `closure-common`.